# django-haystack autocomplete not working as it should

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using:

- `Django : 1.7.1`
- `django-haystack : 2.4.1`
- and `elastic search 2.x` as engine

Index Class

```
class WarehouseIndex(SearchIndex, Indexable):
    """
    SearchIndex Class that stored indexes for Model Warehouse
    """
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    search_auto = EdgeNgramField()
    search_auto2 = NgramField()
    ....

   def get_model(self):
        return WareHouse

    def prepare(self, obj):
        self.prepared_data = super(WarehouseIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        search_auto = [obj.name, obj.sublocality, 
                       obj.locality, obj.city]
        self.prepared_data['search_auto'] = ' '.join(
            [x.lower() for x in search_auto if x is not None])
        self.prepared_data['search_auto2'] = ' '.join(
            [x.lower() for x in search_auto if x is not None])
        return self.prepared_data
```

I have build the index using rebuild_index and running the following code in shell

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet, SQ
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(WareHouse)

>>> sqs.filter(search_auto='pond') # query 1
[]
>>> sqs.filter(search_auto2='pond') # query 2
[]
>>> sqs.filter(search_auto__startswith='pond') # query 3
[<SearchResult: base.warehouse (pk=u'1')>, <SearchResult: base.warehouse (pk=u'22')> ...]

>>> sqs.filter(search_auto2__startswith='pond') # # query 4
[<SearchResult: base.warehouse (pk=u'1')>, <SearchResult: base.warehouse (pk=u'22')> ...]
```

As you can see, 
query 1 and 2 returns "No result"
query 3 and 4 returns "same result" even when seach_auto and search_auto2 are both different  of field type EdgeNgramField and NgramField.

EDIT: [Index mapping](http://dpaste.com/3VYHD6Z), [Index Setting](http://dpaste.com/0754EJS)

EDIT: on futhere inspection I have noticed that haystack is treating my EdgeNgramField and NgramField as CharField - here are the [term vectors](http://dpaste.com/0094PB0), both are same

EDIT: On further inspection I found `haystack/backend/elasticsearch_backend.py` was silently parsing `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError` ([full trace here](http://dpaste.com/0RTB8NX)) when trying to setup the mapping for the index.

why is my index not getting created properly? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the output of `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: @Val - i have added a link to mapping.

Comment: I'd need to see the index settings, too. But it looks like your mapping is basic (i.e. all default types) and doesn't have any custom analyzer (ngram, etc) set on your fields.

Comment: @Val I have not set any custom analyzer or anything i am only using basic django-haystack. do i have to set analyzer too?

Comment: @Val .. added a link

Comment: @Val could my haystack be broken in certain way such that it is not able to understand Edgengram and NgramField? because its mapping them as charField, see the 3rd link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RequestError` you linked to indeed provides a useful hint.

You seem to be using ES 2.x and Haystack uses the `_boost` meta field which [has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#migration-meta-fields) starting with ES 2.0.

You can see that there is an issue ([#1247](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1247#issuecomment-181051014)) about making Haystack work with ES 2.0 and it is still open.

What you can do at this point is either to install [ES 1.7.5](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-5) instead and it will work.

Or wait until [the fix](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/commit/1a7622208fd24479fec2e7704b6a94397149bae9) gets released in a new Haystack version.

Comment: Yes Once I found that error i was able to trace it to the issue too, removing boost meta and got the index working locally, On production will either go with your suggestion or fork django-haystack  and use that till issue is resolved.

Comment: Anything else you need?

Comment: would be able to tell me why ngram-field is returning results based on substring of the  `query` provided.

Comment: I think it's best to create a new question for this, as it's is a different issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542965/ngramfield-returning-resutls-based-on-substring-of-the-query-term