# NgramField returning resutls based on substring of the query term

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a Warehouse Model which is getting index as follows

```
class WarehouseIndex(SearchIndex, Indexable):
    """
    SearchIndex Class that stored indexes for Model Warehouse
    """
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    search_auto = NgramField()
    ....

   def get_model(self):
        return WareHouse
```

In my shell I am running the following sqs query.

```
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(WareHouse)
>>> sqs.filter(customers=3).filter(search_auto='pondicherry')
```

This returns result consisting of results that do not have exact term `pondicherry` it also provides me some results that match terms like `ich`, `che`, `ndi`, etc.

I have even tried using `__exact` and `Exact` but all return the same result?

EDIT: [Index mapping](http://dpaste.com/3J9W3A6), [Index Setting](http://dpaste.com/1KR6BXW)

How can I avoid this and provide result only of term `pondicherry`?

Comment: Can you show your mapping?

Comment: @Val : Mapping and Setting added

Comment: This is because your `search_auto` ngram field has the same index and search analyzer and hence your search term `pondicherry` also gets ngramed at search time. The only way to fix this is to set a different `search_analyzer` for your `search_auto` field, `standard` would be a good fit. Seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1057)

Comment: @Val how do i set seach_analyzer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Val has stated in the above answer, the error was because search_analyzer and indexed_analyzer are same which caused the issue,

As we all know `haystack` is very inflexible in setting up the basic elasticsearch configuration, I installed [elasticstack](http://elasticstack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and in my setting.py changed the backend to it's `elasticsearch_backend` as suggest and additionally added the following 2 configurations

```
# elasticslack setting
ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER = 'snowball'
ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_NGRAM_SEARCH_ANALYZER = 'standard'
```

this seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to this [open issue](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1057)

This is because your `search_auto` ngram field has the same index and search analyzer and hence your search term `pondicherry` also gets ngramed at search time. The only way to fix this is to set a different `search_analyzer` for your `search_auto` field, `standard` would be a good fit.

You can change your `search_auto` field mapping with this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/haystack/_mapping/modelresult -d '{
   "properties": {
      "search_auto": {
         "type": "string",
         "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
         "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
   }
}'
```